# How to purchase 1.5 return tickets?

Tags: tickets

I am looking to book a return ticket to Australia soon. I have a friend there who would like to come with me home, meaning on a one way ticket. Is there any way I can book my own return ticket and their one way ticket in the same order?

If not, I have another question: Whenever I search for the single one way ticket from Australia and back here, it doesn't show up on any search engines, even though it is part of my return ticket. Is there anyway I can get the option to purchase it?

Comment: It’s surprising the flight does not show up. It might be very expensive (one way tickets often do not get the discounts return tickets do), but it should be there. What flights, what date?

Comment: Bergen - Melbourne
Monday, July 22
26h20m 2 Stops

Melbourne - Bergen
Monday, July 29
32h20m 2 Stops.

I am trying to get the second one as a single ticket. Both of them are finnair and found on skyscanner

Comment: @Jesper If the flight numbers are QF37, AY132, AY941: I can definitely see (and book) this connection as a one-way for 2061 AUD. But is this really advisable to book? The cheapest connection on this day costs 1146 AUD and takes 29:50h, while the fastest one costs 1393 AUD and takes 24:30h. So the itinerary that you want is not ideal in any way, which is why it might make sense to just meet up in Bergen.

Comment: Why is it important to you to book both in one order? What would be the benefit over separate tickets?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not do this - at least, not on a single booking.

A single booking (PNR) can have multiple passengers on it, but only if the flight details are exactly the same, meaning that you would need to be on the same route for all flights, which obviously you can't do when one flight is a one-way and the other is a return.

This shouldn't stop you from booking the flights as a one-way though, and indeed I can find flights that seem to match your description by searching via Google Flights and then selecting to purchase via Finair.

[image]

In a more generic sense it certainly is possible that you can find flights that can be booked as a part of a round-trip that can not be booked as a one-way - especially when booking international flights.  This can be due to any number of reasons including government regulations, commercial agreements between airlines, or just simple that the airline hasn't created a 'fare' for the route as a one-way trip.  However based on the search above, that's not the case here.